# MySQL - Convert blob to visible html using Javascript(Node)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

I have an HTML input which accepts jpg files, and I am using Nodejs.

They get sent to my MySQL as a BLOB.

If I try to display them in any way, only the name of the image gets returned, not the base64/binary(?) that is needed to display them on the website.

```
connection.query(`SELECT image FROM image`, function(error,result){ *something* }
```

(I tried switching from img to h1 to maybe see if it would work, it only gave me the filename)

```
<img 
  id='base64image'  
  alt="" 
  src=<% result.forEach(function(element){ %>
    <%= element.image  %> <% }) 
  %>  
>
```

In MySQL, if I rightclick the blob and "Open value in viewer", I can see the binary and text(name) of the image.

How do I show the image properly?

Thank you.

(There are a million questions like this, but they are for PHP)

Comment: Firstly, you're trying to insert every single image into the src attribute of 1 image tag.  Secondly, what are you talking to MySql with?  If it's javascript then I have to assume it's a Node.js application.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Archer Yes, it is a node app.  The way EJS works, is, it creates an IMG for each thing in result, which is every blob in DB.